# Series or list index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of group IDs:

```
letters = ['A', 'A/D', 'B', 'B/D', 'C', 'C/D', 'D']
```

and a dataframe of groups:

```
groups = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['B', 'A/D', 'D', 'D', 'A']})
```

I'd like to create a column in the dataframe that gives the position of the group ids in the list, like so:

```
  group group_idx
0     B         2
1   A/D         1
2     D         6
3     D         6
4     A         0
```

My current solution is this:

```
group_to_num = {hsg: i for i, hsg in enumerate(letters)}
groups['group_idx'] = groups.applymap(lambda x: group_to_num.get(x)).max(axis=1).fillna(-1).astype(np.int32)
```

but it seems inelegant. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try merge after a dataframe constructor:

```
groups.merge(pd.DataFrame(letters).reset_index(),left_on='group',right_on=0).\
           rename(columns={'index':'group_idx'}).drop(0,1)

   group  group_idx
0     B        2
1   A/D        1
2     D        6
3     D        6
4     A        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
import pandas as pd

letters = ['A', 'A/D', 'B', 'B/D', 'C', 'C/D', 'D']
group_to_num = {hsg: i for i, hsg in enumerate(letters)}
groups = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['B', 'A/D', 'D', 'D', 'A']})

groups['group_idx'] = groups.group.map(group_to_num)
print(groups)
```

**Output**

```
  group  group_idx
0     B          2
1   A/D          1
2     D          6
3     D          6
4     A          0
```